# why i cant get the output for categorize?

Tags: java, if-statement, input, while-loop

I must make a Java program that receives student data and stops at -1, then displays the number of grades and their average, and finally, it will display the grades in categories A, B, C, D. This code has an error only when displaying the categories. I need help. In it I will put the desired output

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter 5 grades and then -1 to quit!");
        System.out.print("enter grade:");
        double grade = input.nextDouble();
        double total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int A = 0;
        int B = 0;
        int C = 0;
        int D = 0;
        int F = 0;

        while (grade != -1) {
            total = total + grade;
            System.out.print("enter grade:");
            grade = input.nextDouble();
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println("the number of grades= " + count);
        System.out.println("Average: " + total / count);

        if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100) {
            A++;
        } else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89) {
            B++;
        } else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79) {
            C++;
        } else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 69) {
            D++;
        } else if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 59) {
            F++;
        }
        
        System.out.println("number of A grades :" + A);
        System.out.println("number of B grades :" + B);
        System.out.println("number of C grades :" + C);
        System.out.println("number of D grades :" + D);
        System.out.println("number of F grades :" + F);
    }
}
```

the output should be :

enter grade:90
enter grade:99
enter grade:97
enter grade:98
enter grade:87
enter grade:-1
the number of grades= 5
Average:94.2

Total number of A grades :4
Total number of B grades :1
Total number of C grades :0
Total number of D grades :0
Total number of F grades :0

but instead i got this :

enter grade:90
enter grade:99
enter grade:97
enter grade:98
enter grade:87
enter grade:-1
the number of grades= 5
Average:94.2

Total number of A grades :0
Total number of B grades :0
Total number of C grades :0
Total number of D grades :0
Total number of F grades :0

can someone please tells me why its not working?

Comment: what is the value of `grade` variable after `while (grade!=-1)` loop?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that you are checking the grade after the while loop has completed, which means the `grade` variable contains the value of -1 at that point, and you are only evaluating that one value for the grade categories. You should be checking the categories inside the loop while reading the grades. Here's the corrected code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter 5 grades and then -1 to quit!");
        double total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int A = 0;
        int B = 0;
        int C = 0;
        int D = 0;
        int F = 0;

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter grade (or -1 to quit): ");
            double grade = input.nextDouble();

            if (grade == -1) {
                break;  // Exit the loop when -1 is entered
            }

            total += grade;
            count++;

            if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100) {
                A++;
            } else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89) {
                B++;
            } else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79) {
                C++;
            } else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 69) {
                D++;
            } else if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 59) {
                F++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The number of grades = " + count);
        System.out.println("Average: " + total / count);

        System.out.println("Number of A grades: " + A);
        System.out.println("Number of B grades: " + B);
        System.out.println("Number of C grades: " + C);
        System.out.println("Number of D grades: " + D);
        System.out.println("Number of F grades: " + F);
    }
}
```

With this code, you check the grade categories as you receive each grade within the loop, and it will produce the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... This code has an error only when displaying the categories. ...
>
>
>
> ... can someone please tells me why its not working?"*

The reason this happens is because you're checking the value of *grade*, which after the *loop*, is *−1*.

Additionally, you should gather the *input* values uniformly.
And, re-factor the *grade* *if-statements*.

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.println("enter 5 grades and then -1 to quit!");
double grade;
double total=0;
int count=0;
int A= 0;
int B= 0;
int C = 0;
int D= 0;
int F = 0;
boolean exit = false;

do {
    System.out.print("enter grade:");
    grade=input.nextDouble();
    if (grade == -1) exit = true;
    else {
        total = total + grade;
        count++;
        if(grade>=90) A++;
        else if(grade>=80) B++;
        else if(grade>=70) C++;
        else if(grade>=60) D++;
        else F++;
    }
} while (!exit);


System.out.println("the number of grades= "+ count);
System.out.println("Average: " + total/count);


System.out.println("number of A grades :"+ A);
System.out.println("number of B grades :"+ B);
System.out.println("number of C grades :"+ C);
System.out.println("number of D grades :"+ D);
System.out.println("number of F grades :"+ F);
```

Output

```
enter 5 grades and then -1 to quit!
enter grade:90
enter grade:80
enter grade:70
enter grade:-1
the number of grades= 3
Average: 80.0
number of A grades :1
number of B grades :1
number of C grades :1
number of D grades :0
number of F grades :0
```

Comment: thankkkkk yoooouuu so much im crying it worked !!!

Answer (score 0):

When you exit the loop and reaches to the `if-else` part, the value of `grade` is `-1` so none of the conditions will be true.

You need to move the `if-else` part into the `while` loop:

```
    while (grade!=-1){
    total += grade;

    if(grade>=90 && grade<=100){
        A++;}
    else if(grade>=80 && grade<=89){
        B++;}
    else if(grade>=70 && grade<=79){
        C++;}
    else if(grade>=60 && grade<=69){
        D++;}
    else if(grade>=0 && grade<=59){
        F++;}
    count++;
    System.out.print("enter grade:");
    grade=input.nextDouble();
    }
```

### Output:

```
enter 5 grades and then -1 to quit!
enter grade:90
enter grade:99
enter grade:97
enter grade:98
enter grade:87
enter grade:-1
the number of grades= 5
Average: 94.2
number of A grades :4
number of B grades :1
number of C grades :0
number of D grades :0
number of F grades :0
```

---

## Edit:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Grades {
public static void main(String []args){   
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("enter 5 grades and then -1 to quit!");
 System.out.print("enter grade:");
 double grade=input.nextDouble();
 double total=0;
 int count=0;
 int A= 0;
 int B= 0;
 int C = 0;
 int D= 0;
 int F = 0;
 
 
while (grade!=-1){
    total += grade;
    if(grade>=90 && grade<=100){
        A++;}
    else if(grade>=80 && grade<=89){
        B++;}
    else if(grade>=70 && grade<=79){
        C++;}
    else if(grade>=60 && grade<=69){
        D++;}
    else if(grade>=0 && grade<=59){
        F++;}
    count++;
    System.out.print("enter grade:");
    grade=input.nextDouble();
}
    
    
 System.out.println("the number of grades= "+ count);
 System.out.println("Average: " + total/count);
 

System.out.println("number of A grades :"+ A);
System.out.println("number of B grades :"+ B);
System.out.println("number of C grades :"+ C);
System.out.println("number of D grades :"+ D);
System.out.println("number of F grades :"+ F);
    
}   
}
```

Comment: if part should be before `nextDouble` otherwise very first value read will be skipped (it is read at the very start of main)

Comment: @IłyaBursov Yeah, I just forgot to save the edits :)

Comment: thanks for the answer i am really happy you helped me! i did what you told me and its works! but theres one mistake its gave me 6 grades while i entered 5 grades with -1 so how i could solve this please?

Comment: @sera Hi, I attached the output..

Comment: sorry to bother but it still gave me 6 instead of 5 <\\3

Comment: can you help me i wanna use your answer!:(

Comment: @sera I now attached the full version, you can copy it or try to see what you did differently :)

Comment: I felt stressed because of this application and you really saved my life. Thank you. I wish you good health

Comment: @sera Please consider accepting my answer :)